# Hide all Objects on sheet

Tags: excel, vba

In my Workbook I have a macro to hide all objects on the sheet.

It worked until today.

```
Sub Hiding()
    Dim sObject As Object
    Dim a As Integer, v As Integer

'Count all visible Worksheets
    v = 0
    For Each s In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        If s.Visible = True Then
            v = v + 1
        End If
    Next s

'Hide all Objects
    For a = 2 To v
        For Each sObject In Worksheets(a).Shapes
            sObject.Visible = False
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

I also tried `Dim sObject As Shape`

Comment: Can't you just replace `v` with `ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count`, and delete the first loop entirely?  (You also aren't including a failsafe check for when there are less than 2 Worksheets in the Workbook)

Answer (score 1):

The Visible Worksheets.Count that you create with the v=v+1 loop should be an array of the visible worksheet ordinal indices, not a total of the visible worksheets. When you cycle through a, a should retrieve the value in the array, not simply a *1, 2,3*, etc worksheet index number.

```
dim w as long, v as long, a as long, vws as variant

'prep vars
v = 0
redim vws(1 to ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count)

'IDENTIFY all visible Worksheets
For w=2 to ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.count    'note I started at the 2nd worksheet here
    If ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(w).Visible Then
        v = v + 1
        vws(v) = w
    End If
Next s

redim preserve vws(1 to v)

'Hide all Objects
For a = lbound(vws) To ubound(vws)
    For Each sObject In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(vws(a)).Shapes
        sObject.Visible = False
    Next
Next
```